# Creating subfolder

Tags: c#, subdirectory

I have little problem with converting, I try to convert folder where is subfolders but its not creating subfolders, makes only one folder "_converted" and in the folder is all converted subfolder images.

My code:

```
private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] originalImage = Directory.GetDirectories(txtFilePath.Text, "*.*", 
                                                            SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (var directory in originalImage)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(directory);
    }
    foreach (string dir in originalImage)
    {

        string folderPath = @"C:\test\" + "_converted";
        folderPath = folderPath.Substring(folderPath.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
        if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        {
            DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
            foreach (var filename in dInfo.GetFiles())
            {

                FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(filename.FullName);
                var fileExtension = fInfo.Extension;
                var fileOriginalDate = fInfo.CreationTime;

                if (fileExtension.ToUpper() == ".JPG" || fileExtension.ToUpper() == ".PNG")
                {
                    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(filename.FullName))
                    {
                        string fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename.FullName);
                        VariousQuality(bitmap, fn, fileExtension, 
                                              fileOriginalDate, folderPath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use this method:

```
folderPath = folderPath.Substring(folderPath.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);
```

How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Why are you looping twice to say first ? Can't you move the Debug call to the second loop ?

Comment: Yes but this isnt fix this problem..

Comment: Why do you do this `folderPath.Substring(folderPath.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);` ? + There is no place in your code where you create sub-folders. You only create a folder in one place and it is a static string assigned to `C:\test\_converted`

Comment: I thinked this creating all folders.

Comment: That converts `C:\test\_converted` to `\test\_converted` so it is creating folders in the same folder as your running exe. Which is most probably `ProjectLocation\Bin\Debug\test\_converted`

Comment: Do you wan to create the same Hierarchy of folders that is in `txtFilePath.Text` inside `C:\test\_converted`

Comment: I choose folder where is images "Images" and in Images folder are more folders like "image1", "image2" and "image3" and now if I convert it must go to ` C:\test\ ` and folders are "image1_converted", image2_converted and image3_converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not handling the folders' names correctly. Try this:

```
private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] originalImage = Directory.GetDirectories(txtFilePath.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (var directory in originalImage)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(directory);
    }
    foreach (string dir in originalImage)
    {
        // The name of the current folder (dir)
        // This will convert "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Myfolder\Image1" to simply "Image1" since we create a substring after the LAST backslash ('\')
        string folderName = dir.Substring(dir.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1); // Ex. "Image1"

        // This will now be "C:\test\FOLDERNAME_converted"
        string folderPath = @"C:\test\" + folderName + @"_converted\"; // Ex. "C:\test\image1_converted\";

        // This can now create the folders
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

        // Below is unchanged for now
        if (Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        {
            DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
            foreach (var filename in dInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(filename.FullName);
                var fileExtension = fInfo.Extension;
                var fileOriginalDate = fInfo.CreationTime;

                if (fileExtension.ToUpper() == ".JPG" || fileExtension.ToUpper() == ".PNG")
                {
                    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(filename.FullName))
                    {
                        string fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename.FullName);
                        VariousQuality(bitmap, fn, fileExtension,
                                              fileOriginalDate, folderPath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I Hope this helps.

I just have one question. When getting the directories in your directory path (`txtFilePath.Text`), you get all folders including subfolders (`SearchOptions.AllDirectories`). When saving the converted folders to the "`C:\test`" folder, you don't take into account that a folder could have been a subfolder. Because of this the following problem happens. Let's say you have a folder with a folder with a folder:

```
"HeadFolder -> Image1 -> Image1.2"
```

What the program will find:

```
1. "Path\\To\\Image1"
2. "Path\\To\\Image1.2"
```

After converting you'll get:

```
"HeadFolder"
    "Image1"
    "Image1.2"
```

Notice that "Image1.2" does NOT end up inside "Image1" as prior to conversion

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working!

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the same folder in each iteration of the loop. Just create a folder using the current directory by replacing the below lines:

```
string folderPath = @"C:\test\" + "_converted";
folderPath = folderPath.Substring(folderPath.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);
```

With this line:

```
string folderPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\test\", dir + "_converted");
```